# Bijection between $n$-partitions and "flattened" canonical $n+1$-partitions

Tags: combinatorics

The set of $n$-partitions (partitions of the set $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$) and the set of "flattened" canonical $(n+1)$-partitions (those permutations obtained by removing the bars from an $(n+1)$ partition written in canonical form) are both counted by the Bell number $B(n)$. Can you give an intuitive bijection between these two sets?

Comment: I can see the $5$ partitions of $\{1,2,3\}$ ($1$ all together, $3$ with one alone and two together, and $1$ with each separate) but what are the $5$ "flattened partitions" of $\{1,2,3,4\}$?

Comment: So the 15 partitions of $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$, written in canonical form, are: $1234$, $1|234$, $134|2$, $124|3$, $123|4$, $12|34$, $13|24$, $14|23$, $1|2|34$, $1|24|3$, $1|23|4$, $14|2|3$, $13|2|4$, $12|3|4$ and $1|2|3|4$.

When you flatten them, the 5 unique permutations obtained are $1234$, $1342$, $1243$, $1324$ and $1423$.

Comment: @Snufsan: jaakhaamer's point is that the "flattened partitions" end up with $5$ corresponding permutations and I asked for $5$

Answer (score 1):

In one of our recent article (see link below Section 4):

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/344683169_Run_Distribution_Over_Flattened_Partitions
we gave a bijection between set partitions of $[n]$ and flattened partitions of length $[n+1]$.
**For example**: Let us consider a partition $P = 12|3|45$ of $[5]$. Then re-ordering the entries of $P$ such that in each block, the smallest entry appears at the end, then we would have a new partition $P' = 21|3|54$. Increasing by 1, each of the entries in $P'$ gives $P* = 32|4|65$. The corresponding flattened partition is obtained by appending a "1" before $P*$ and ignoring the vertical marks "|" separating the blocks, i.e., $1P* = 132465$, which is a flattened partition of length 6.

Moreover, using now the flattened partition $1P* = 132465$, we can get back $P$ by inserting the vertical mark "|" immediately after each right to left minimum gives $1|32|4|65|$. Deleting 1 and re-ordering the remaining
gives the partition $P = 12|3|45$.

For technicalities and details of the bijection, please refer to the above link.